# Proof of average of the function formula

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I tried to prove the average of the function formula which states that the average of a function $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$ is

$$\text{Average of $f$ on $[a,b]$} = {{1}\over{b-a}} \int_a^b {f(x)}dx$$

And I found the proof uses the direct definition of the average "Sum of values over their numbers" and the definition of the definite integral "Limit of Riemann sum".

So, I tried something else that used the fundamental theorem of calculus instead.

Define a function $F$ where $\int {f(x)} dx = F(x) + C$
Since function $f$ is the derivative of the function $F$ "Its rate of change", so the average rate of change of $F$ on an interval $[a,b]$ is the average of the function $f$ on the same interval

Since the average rate of change of $F$ on $[a,b]$ $=$ ${{F(b) - F(a)}\over{b-a}}$

And since the fundamental theorem of calculus states that:

$$\int_a^b {f(x)}dx = F(b) - F(a)$$

So the average rate of change of $F$ on $[a,b]$ $=$ ${{1}\over{b-a}} \int_a^b {f(x)}dx$ and then:

$$\text{Average of $f$ on $[a,b]$} = {{1}\over{b-a}} \int_a^b {f(x)}dx$$

I find this proof much easier and if we take in consideration the fundamental theorem of calculus but I never found anybody prove it this way. Is this proof not "rigorous" enough? And if not, what is wrong about it?

Comment: This seems fine, but you may have seen the proof written for an integrable function $f$. The FTC holds for continuous functions (which is a stronger notion than integrability).

Comment: So the only difference is that the proof in the question assumes the continuity of the function while the original proof assumes the integrability of the function "which doesn't necessarily imply continuity"?

Comment: There's a slight issue with your definition of $F$. I think you meant to write $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(y) dy + C$? This indefinite integral may also introduce some issues with rigor that need to be sorted out.

Comment: Issues like what?

Comment: $f_{avg}$ does not depend on $x$, for any given function, it is a constant that depends only on the endpoints $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @ww1 Ok I edited the proof

Comment: @YousefEssam If we only know that $f(x)$ is integrable (as opposed to continuous), then we don't necessarily have an antiderivative $F(x)$ such that
$$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=F(b)-F(a) $$
Also, what's your definition of average

Comment: I already mentioned this in the question. Average or mean of a set of values is the sum of its values divided by their number.

Comment: And thanks for pointing out about this, I now understand how my proof is different from the original proof, where the original proof assumes integrability which is more abstract than continuity "A continuous function on an interval is integrable on the same interval, the converse is not always true", while here the proof just assumes continuity of the function.